# wildfly (9) + kerberos + ldap (Active Directory)

Tags: java, authentication, ldap, wildfly, kerberos

I'm trying to get to point, where wildfly 9 would be able to authenticate users with kerberos and authorize them with ldap.

I'm having rich EJB client using JAAS (having `com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule`).

I'd need some sample including the step-by-step configuration.

What I've found is:

- wildfly with LDAP (https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/LDAPSecurityRealmExamples)
- wildfly with SPNEGO (https://github.com/kwart/spnego-demo)
- wildfly with kerberos for server management (http://darranl.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/wildfly-9-kerberos-authentication-for.html, 
  http://darranl.blogspot.co.uk/2014/11/wildfly-9-kerberos-authentication-with.html)

however I have not web but rich application + I'm not using LDAP for authentication, but kerberos. And I need not only management operations to be authenticated using kerberos.

Any complete sample/references out there?

Comment: Haven't looked into the links deeply but you could easily port my code from [Tomcat](http://tomcatspnegoad.sourceforge.net/) Wildfly. It will give you want to need.

Answer (score 1):

i manage to make it work with this library :

https://github.com/dstraub/spnego-wildfly

you incorpore the jar in your application (not available in MVN repository), then you have to specify the mechanism authentication "SPNEGO" for example in web.xml, configure your active directory, create your keytab, configure your standalone.xml or domain.xml and it is OK , you can also use an apache in front and a load balancer, an example with the sample-app

Comment: hey, thanks for reply, it's nice, but, I'd need rich app, any chance for sample with that?

Comment: basically web-free client

Comment: hi, i did it in a JSF web application , sorry for my english what means for you a rich app please ?, i begun with the example, make it work and then next step a real application -) ith ldap realms...